# ASP.NET 'CommandType' is not a member of 'Data' all of the sudden

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I was trying to install some new DLL's on my site and I've created a site wide issue.  I don't really know how to fix this, but I feel like it should be relatively simple.   I think I've deleted a reference or a dll or something.

Everywhere I call a stored procedure I was setting the CommandType with this syntax: `CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure`

This no longer works, it says 'CommandType' is not a member of 'Data'.  If I rewrite each statement like this the page works again: `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

What have I done to my site?  Any insight?

Comment: Do you have Imports System?

Comment: Yes, I didn't change any aspx pages.  Looking at a couple of pages that now error, they have this Import:  `Imports System.Data`

Comment: Then you can remove the Data part from CommandType. No more necessary and probably confusing

Comment: Yea, doing that makes the page work again.  I'm just scared that I have deleted or unreferenced something crucial.  I don't really want to go through the entire site and remove the "Data.", is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Actually I think it is a bigger issues than that.  Other pages are kicking back messages like this now: `'AllowMultiple' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'
'PostedFiles' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'`